# cdn: proxy request to specific origin based on ip geolocation

Tags: geolocation, cdn

I have a service with a few origin servers, each in a different continent. Every client request goes through a cdn that proxies to these servers. About half of requests are cacheable and the other half are not. It doesn't matter much which of the origins serves the cacheable responses because the distributed CDN will handle serving that response from the closest possible POP for those requests in the future (until cache expiration). However, for uncacheable responses, I'd like for the closest origin to the user to respond to requests that the CDN is proxying.

Is there such a feature that some CDNs have whereby you can specify something like: "make a best effort to geocode the request based on ip, if the ip is from continent north america use `noram.originfoo.com`, if the ip is from continent europe use `eu.originfoo.com`, etc"?

Maybe the architecture should instead be that DNS resolution chooses a CDN hostname based on the client ip and the CDN has different entries whereby one region specific-CDN hostname maps to one origin hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) CDN solution. It uses [varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) and allows for [vcl](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl.html) rules to be used by the customer (see their [docs](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/vcl/guide-to-vcl#)). 
Here's a [guide](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/performance-tuning/changing-origins-based-on-user-location) that appears to be doing what you need:

> Fastly allows you to change origin servers based on the user's geographic location. This is useful when you need to serve different content to users who are in different locations. For example, you could change origin servers to serve a restricted version of your website to users in a different country.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an existing services that does this of course, AWS for sure can do this. But if you want to implement this yourself you would basically need to find the location of the caller via their IP, and according to that send them the URL to the closest location.

Comment: could you give more details on how it could be accomplished in AWS?

Comment: The easiest way is to use AWS CloudFront, they will already do this for you out of the box.

Comment: could you share a link to a document describing that CloudFront would pick a custom origin closest to the user's ip? Thanks

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: the link provided doesn't seem to be related - the question is about choosing the right _origin_ location, not an _edge_ location. Looks like we're talking about different things